# ADO Recordset não retorna nada

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado

não consigo fazer o ADO Recordset retornar os registros de uma tabela do MySQL. Estou usando VB.NET no Visual Studio. 
Consigo estabelecer a comunicação com o banco de dados, faço a conexão, crio tabelas, tudo via objeto de conexão (conforme abaixo) mas na hora de retornar as informações via Recordset, dá erro.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim aux As String

aux = "Provider = MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}; Server=localhost; Database = db-teste; User=root; Password=123456; Option=3;"
conn.Open(aux)

'create table
conn.Execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_ado")
conn.Execute("CREATE TABLE my_ado(id int Not null primary key, name varchar(20)," &
                "txt text, dt date, tm time, ts timestamp)")
'insert
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO my_ado(id,name,txt) values(1,100,'venu')")
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO my_ado(id,name,txt) values(2,200,'MySQL')")

'============================================================================
' ATÉ AQUI VINHA FUNCIONANDO OK!
'============================================================================


' Isso não retorna nada
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM my_ado", conn)
rs.MoveFirst()

' RecordCount retorna sempre "-1" <<<<<<====================
Debug.Print(Str(rs.RecordCount()))

' rs.Fields já vem com erro
For Each fld In rs.Fields 
    Debug.Print(fld.Name)
Next
```

O que está errado?

Comment: cara, ja verificou se esse sql retorna alguma coisa direto no banco de dados? `SELECT * FROM my_ado`
Verificou se a conexao que esta apssando em `rs.Open("SELECT * FROM my_ado", conn)` realmente esta apontando pro lugar certo ?

Comment: se isso e vb.net pq usa recordset? nao é possivel utilizar algo como datareader? `https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2`

Comment: Olá @MeAjudaSilvio. Sim, eu verifiquei direto no banco de dados se a tabela é criada (é criada e os registros estão lá também). Até o ponto onde coloquei o comentário "ATÉ AQUI VINHA FUNCIONANDO OK!", o código está perfeito. Após esse ponto do comentário a coisa deixa de fazer sentido. Estou usando VB no Visual Studio 2017. Sim, dá para fazer com "datareader" sem problemas, porém neste caso específico estou precisando fazer com o ADODB, até porque não dá para aceitar a falta de solução desse problema, mesmo que fosse só por curiosidade.